# Incorrect year in the date when trying to insert in database using jdbc, SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, oracle, date, jdbc, simpledateformat

I've been trying to insert a date into the Oracle database using JDBC, SimpleDateFormat API. 
When I passed the date as "2016-07-24", it is inserting as "24-JUL-24" which is wrong (year is wrong), it should suppose to be "24-JUL-16". It's happening once in a nth time. I was unable to debug the code, although I tried repeatedly inserting the data. 
Could anyone please refer the below code, db schema and date format and let me know if I'm wrong anywhere. Thank you.

DAO Program

```
    package com.oog.big.database;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import com.oog.big.database.DBConnection;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

    public class ItemDetailsDAO {
    // format for date  
    public static final SimpleDateFormat transactionDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd");
    public static transient final SimpleDateFormat requestDateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    private static final String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO ITEM_DETAILS ("
            + "    ITEM_ID                    ,"
            + "    SRV_NAME               ,"
            + "    INS_TYPE            ,"
            + "    REQ_CONTEXT            ,"
            + "    STATUS_FLAG     ,"
            + "    CHL                    ,"
            + "    TRANSACTION_DATE           ,"
            + "    REQ_DATETIME           ,"
            + "    FLAG          )" + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    public static void save() throws Exception {

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        try {
            con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            con.setAutoCommit(true);

                stmt = con.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
                stmt.setInt(1, 1256);
                stmt.setString(2, "DD");
                stmt.setString(3, "OL");
                stmt.setString(4, "DP");
                stmt.setString(5, "");
                stmt.setString(6, "FF");
                /** Incorrect Date **/
                stmt.setDate(
                        7,
                        new java.sql.Date(transactionDateFormat.parse(
                                "2016-07-24").getTime()));
                stmt.setDate(
                        8,
                        new java.sql.Date(requestDateTimeFormat.parse(
                                "2016-08-02T16:56:01.764-04:00").getTime()));
                stmt.setString(9, "N");
                stmt.execute();
                stmt.close();
                System.out.println("Completed!!");

            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("DB Error: "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Schema for `ITEM_DETAILS`

```
CREATE TABLE OYD.ITEM_DETAILS
  (
    ITEM_ID                    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SRV_NAME               VARCHAR2(5) DEFAULT NULL,
    INS_TYPE            VARCHAR2(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    REQ_CONTEXT            VARCHAR2(3) DEFAULT NULL,
    REQ_DATETIME           TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
    STATUS_FLAG     VARCHAR2(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    CHL                    VARCHAR2(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    TRANSACTION_DATE           DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    FLAG          VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP      TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ITEM_DETAILS PRIMARY KEY (ITEM_ID)
  )
PARTITION BY RANGE (LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP) INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
(
PARTITION P_ITEM_DETAILS VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('07-MAR-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'))
)PARALLEL;
```

### Specifications:

- JAVA SE8
- Oracle 12c database
- JDBC Connector: ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.0.jar

Comment: One remark SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe so it should not be a static field, you are supposed to create a new instance at each call

Comment: There are two disturbing things here: 1. why go through a formatting primitive when the columns in the database are date/time types? 2. why is a column a `DATE` and another a `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: If this is not happening 100% consistently on all input, then the problem is in the input data.  You haven't shown samples of successful and failing input, nor have you shown the code that parses the input, making it impossible for anybody here to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of formatting date using SimpleDateFormat, you can use Oracle's date function in your SQL.

```
private static final String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO ITEM_DETAILS ("
        + "    ITEM_ID,"
        + "    SRV_NAME,"
        + "    INS_TYPE,"
        + "    REQ_CONTEXT,"
        + "    STATUS_FLAG,"
        + "    CHL,"
        + "    TRANSACTION_DATE,"
        + "    REQ_DATETIME,"
        + "    FLAG)" + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,TO_DATE(?,'DD-MON-RR'),TO_DATE(?,'DD-MON-RR'),?)";

public static void save(){
//.........
smtp.setString(7,"24-07-2016");
smtp.setString(8,"02-8-2016");
//.........
```

You can even format time(hh:mm:ss) in TO_DATE() function to store timestamp.